# Determining if a MethodInfo maps to a function that uses the `params` keyword

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, parameters

I am using reflection to invoke methods based on scripts that users enter in to my application. When trying to map script tokens to `MethodInfo` objects, I want to filter out methods that use the `params` keyword since argument verification for these functions would be different than that of functions with a fixed number of parameters.

```
public double Average (params double [] parameters) {...}
```

In reflection, the parameter type shows as only `double []` with no indication that `params` was specified at compile time. Am I missing something or is that information lost during compilation. The objective is to find out whether a function was intended to use a variable number of parameters.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That information can be found in the parameters of your method - not in the `MethodInfo`.

Therefore, you should check if the `ParameterInfo` is decorated with the `[ParamArrayAttribute]`. As the [params modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) can only be applied to the last parameter of your method, I suppose something like this should work:

```
public bool MethodHasParams(MethodInfo mi) {
    var lastParameter = mi.GetParameters().LastOrDefault();
    if(lastParameter == null) return false;

    return lastParameter.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (ParamArrayAttribute), false).Length > 0;
}
```

Comment: The `ParamArrayAttribute` is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!